# ReactiveUI: most recent version compatible with .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, reactiveui

My application runs on a server that hosts .NET 4.0

What is the most current version of ReactiveUI that is compatible with .NET 4.0?

I read 4.0.2 on the Internet, but I am not sure this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a .Net4 supported branch of RxUI 6.5 [here](https://github.com/gluck/ReactiveUI), and it's also uploaded to Nuget [there](https://www.nuget.org/packages/reactiveui-core.Net40/).

The branch is unofficial (PR to include support in official one was rejected), but it's working well (changes are minimal).

It requires Bcl packages for Task support, but you may be using them already.

Answer (score 0):

ReactiveUI 4.x still supports .NET 4.0. [1]

> ReactiveUI has dropped support for .NET 4.0 starting with version 5. ReactiveUI 5.x support .NET 4.5, Windows Store, Windows Phone 8 and Xamarin. For .NET 4.0 support you can use the 4.x version.

[1] https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/414#issuecomment-29394715

Comment: That's the _official_ statement, I added my own answer for the _unofficial_ one, which I'd recommend instead of using RxUI 4.X